# How to Stop Showing OS X Beta Software Updates in iOS

Tags: ios, software-update

I would like to stop installing beta versions on my iPhone. Without rolling back to an old version ([as described by Apple](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll#ios)) but something similar to http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/05/stop-os-x-beta-software-updates-showing-app-store/

In this particular case I would like to wait for iOS 9 and do not try the 9.1 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hide those beta updates notifications through [Apple's developers console](https://developer.apple.com/).

Also if your iPhone is currently on a beta version you may not be able to hide them unless you upgrade via iTunes to a public release of iOS ( i.e. IOS 9 GM ).

Comment: I am using a public beta so the developers console is most likely not an option. If I install the final iOS 9 with iTunes will it remove the beta profile on the phone? (i.e. hide the next beta updates)?

Comment: @Matteo Yes, doing so *should* do it & you won't be notified again about next beta releases.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it (it did for me)
https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll#ios
Restart your iPhone and Bata Update is gone

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think your answer is better than others out there.  Links do help but just posting a link and telling people to go to it is not what we're trying to accomplish.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review